# Can i connect winCC OA with Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, siemens, wincc-oa

How can I put into the WinCC OA a 3D model like in the Unreal Ungine? I have 3D model which might act in UE, and I want it to fetch data and logic for its actions from WinCC OA. Is it possible to put 3D model into WinCC OA and make it act, or if not, maybe there is a way to make interaction between WinCC OA and UE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way would be to implement an *External Widget Object (EWO)*. *EWOs* are based on *Qt* so you can implement everything you are able to implement in a *QWidget object*. The interaction between WinCC OA and the *EWO* is done by accessing the exposed properties and events of the *EWO* and with *ctrl script*.

The WinCC OA documentation contains a chapter about *EWOs* which is located under *GEDI* -> *complex graphic objects* -> *EWO (External Widget Object)*.

In order to develop an *EWO* you need to install the *API* package. After that you will find example code and tools for development of an *EWO* under *<wincc_oa_path>/api*.